# Unable to install Ubuntu 20.04 on Dell XPS 13 9380

Tags: boot, uefi, dell, xps

I'm trying to install a fresh version of Ubuntu 20.04 on a Dell XPS 13, 9380. This was a machine originally shipped with pre-installed Windows.

**I'm able to install Ubuntu from a USB stick**, but the laptop fails to boot to Ubuntu, when it restarts. I'm simply taken to a GNU Grub command line prompt, or to a MOK management screen, or simply to a screen informing me that there are no bootable devices.

In the BIOS, I have tried the following but to no avail:

1. Trying different .efi files as boots from the `EFI/ubuntu` directory including `mmx64.efi`, `shimx64.efi`, and `grubx64.efi`.
2. Switching the SATA operation to RAID On, instead of AHCI.
3. Enabling/disabling secure boot.
4. I have even updated the BIOS on this machine, using the latest update provided by DELL for this model.

Ultimately, every combination of the above options appear to lead to the same GRUB prompt. Would anyone have any idea what else I could try? Your help would be immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There might be problem with the USB stick itself, please check it in other system once and then try again.If it works there might be something wrong with the partition type of bootable device. I mean if you have used rufus or similar software it'll ask you partition type modern systems partition type is GPT you might have made it in MBR or vice versa. Try another software to make your USB bootable.

Comment: Thanks Adarsh for your suggestion. I've edited the post to emphasize the fact that I actually can install Ubuntu from a USB stick. The problem arises when I restart the laptop, and after I've been asked to remove the USB drive. This was made bootable using the Startup Disk Creator on a different machine.

Comment: @Nicomachus thank you for clarifying the question. I think there might be problem with the installation itself try to reinstall Ubuntu by deleting the partition in which you have previously installed and recreating it ( just to make sure to remove all the traces of previous installation) even if the problem exits try to make it bootable using other softwares like POWERISO. If the problem still arises just check the ISO image that you have downloaded

Comment: thanks again. I have followed your recommendations and created a new bootable using UNetbootin, but this led to the same result. I have also checked the integrity of my ISO file, using CheckSums, as described [here](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#6-check-the-iso). But as I had suspected, the ISO image is OK. I suspect that the problem has to do with the fact that I have deleted the Windows Boot Manager (WBM) in the boot sequence. This should be present to ensure that Ubuntu can access securing booting. But I don't know which file to specify for the WBM in BIOS.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the problem about WBM try to disable secure boot and try with different sequences in boot options if the problem still exits it would be better if any screen shot of boot menu is available

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Adarsh again for your help. I have found the solution to that problem. It was sufficient to **install Ubuntu under Secure Boot**. When you do this, the installation automatically handles the security issues, and allows you to reboot without any problem.

To do so, one needed to **add a boot option** in the BIOS, selecting one of the USB ports on your machine. If you insert your bootable device before start-up, the USB port will be visible, and you just select it when you add a new boot option.